# android know at runtime that text is cut

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView, and i want to know, at runtime, if the text is to long.
The requirement that is making this tricky, and thus haven't found a solution to it, is that I DO NOT want to use ellipsize, because I do NOT want to show three dots at the end.
ideas?
thanks

Comment: The text is to long to display, i.e if the was ellipsize, it would be "lurm ipsum bla bla bla ...".
but the requirement is
1. not to use ellipsize
2. to know that this is the case, at runtime

Comment: In runtime is more difficult ot calculate but not impossible i think...anyway you can also use the other parameter: marquee (android:ellipsize="marquee"). With this parameter, the line will be cutted but the 3 dots won't be shown.

Comment: Is this parameter valid for you?  You should use also the number of lines that you need. android:lines="1"

Comment: guys thatnks for your comments:

user395: All I want to know, is if the text is cut, that's it. nothing to do with width or height.

Juan: android:ellipsize="marquee" does not remove the three dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to check on runtime you have to use a paint object.

doc ref: [Paint.measureText(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)) and [TextView.getPaint()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getPaint())

// the code below must be run AFTER the TextView have been layout on the screen.

```
Paint p = textView.getPaint();
float width = p.measureText("your text here");
if(width > textView.getWidth()){
   // bigger
}
```

`TextUtils` class also have some interesting methods that you might be interested, for example, the method that calculates the ellipsize: [TextUtils.ellipsize(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#ellipsize(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20float,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt))